# Почему некорректно выводится значение вектора чисел?

Tags: c++

Я хочу, чтобы программа выводила **[X, Y]** вектора числа, а у меня выводит **[Y, X]**.

Код:

```
vector<vector<int>> vect = {
    {50, 30},
    {-20, 70},
    {-95, -10}
};

for (int i = 0; i < vect.size(); i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < vect[i].size(); j+=2)
    {
        cout << "Vector " << i << " X, Y:  " << vect[i][j] << ", " << vect[i][j++] << endl;
    }
}
```

Когда я запускаю программу мне выдает:
[image: Вывод консоли]

Я не могу найти ошибку, помогите.

Comment: потому что Ваш код содержит UB. Но я бы сказал, даже двойное. Порядок вычисления подвыражений не очень определен до 17 стандарта. начиная с 17 он чуточку больше определен, но все же. Пишите вот так `vect[i][j+1]`, а не `vect[i][j++]`.

Comment: @KoVadim У меня почемуто выводятся каждый раз случайные числа...

Comment: @KoVadim https://imgur.com/a/SBnJteD

Comment: Выйду с бомбоубежища, посмотрю.

Comment: Вибачте, будь-ласка.

Comment: вот так все работает как нужно `std::cout << "Vector " << i << " X, Y:  " << vect[i][j] << ", " << vect[i][j+1] << std::endl;`  проверял на gcc и clang, 11 и 17 стандарт. (все буде добре)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В коде есть несколько проблем:

1. Во внутреннем цикле нет смысла, ведь он выпонится всего один раз из-за `j += 2`
2. Вывод в обратном порядке скорее всего из-за того, что Вы используете стандарт старше С++17, в котором не определён порядок вычисления аргументов в выводе и `j++` выполнится раньше, чем произойдёт вывод первого числа вектора.
3. Даже включив С++17 Вы увидите проблемы, потому что `j++` увеличит `j` только после вывода.

Может быть лучше сделать так:

```
for (int i = 0; i < vect.size(); i++)
{
    cout << "Vector " << i << " X, Y:  " << vect[i][0] << ", " << vect[i][1] << endl;
}
```